# Comparing sound file and realtime voice with musicg

Tags: android, fft

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    private AudioRecord recorder = null;
    private int bufferSize = 0;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setButtonHandlers();
    enableButtons(false);

    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

}

    private void setButtonHandlers() {
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
    }

    private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
            ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
    }

    private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
            enableButton(R.id.btnStart,!isRecording);
            enableButton(R.id.btnStop,isRecording);
    }

    private String getFilename(){
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

            if(!file.exists()){
                    file.mkdirs();
            }

            return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
    }

    private String getTempFilename(){
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

            if(!file.exists()){
                    file.mkdirs();
            }

            File tempFile = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

            if(tempFile.exists())
                    tempFile.delete();

            return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
    }

    private void startRecording(){
            recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                            RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

            int i = recorder.getState();
            if(i==1)
                recorder.startRecording();

            isRecording = true;

            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            writeAudioDataToFile();
                    }
            },"AudioRecorder Thread");

            recordingThread.start();
    }

    private void writeAudioDataToFile(){
            byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
            String filename = getTempFilename();
            FileOutputStream os = null;

            try {
                    os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int read = 0;

            if(null != os){
                    while(isRecording){
                            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                            if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
                                    try {
                                            os.write(data);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
                    }

                    try {
                            os.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }

    private void stopRecording(){
            if(null != recorder){
                    isRecording = false;

                    int i = recorder.getState();
                    if(i==1)
                        recorder.stop();
                    recorder.release();

                    recorder = null;
                    recordingThread = null;
            }

            copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(),getFilename());
            compareTempFile();
    }

    private void compareTempFile() {
            File file = new File(getTempFilename());
            Wave w1 = new Wave(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.selam));
            Wave w2 = new Wave(file.getPath());


            FingerprintSimilarity fps = w1.getFingerprintSimilarity(w2);
            float score = fps.getScore();
            float sim = fps.getSimilarity();
            System.out.println(sim+" buldum");

    }

    private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename,String outFilename){
            FileInputStream in = null;
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            long totalAudioLen = 0;
            long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
            long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
            int channels = 2;
            long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;

            byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

            try {
                    in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
                    totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
                    totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

                    AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

                    WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

                    while(in.read(data) != -1){
                            out.write(data);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
                    FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
                    long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
                    long byteRate) throws IOException {

            byte[] header = new byte[44];

            header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
            header[1] = 'I';
            header[2] = 'F';
            header[3] = 'F';
            header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
            header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
            header[8] = 'W';
            header[9] = 'A';
            header[10] = 'V';
            header[11] = 'E';
            header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
            header[13] = 'm';
            header[14] = 't';
            header[15] = ' ';
            header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
            header[17] = 0;
            header[18] = 0;
            header[19] = 0;
            header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
            header[21] = 0;
            header[22] = (byte) channels;
            header[23] = 0;
            header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
            header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
            header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
            header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
            header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
            header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
            header[33] = 0;
            header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
            header[35] = 0;
            header[36] = 'd';
            header[37] = 'a';
            header[38] = 't';
            header[39] = 'a';
            header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
            header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
            header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
            header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

            out.write(header, 0, 44);

    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch(v.getId()){
                            case R.id.btnStart:{
                                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                                    enableButtons(true);
                                    startRecording();

                                    break;
                            }
                            case R.id.btnStop:{
                                    AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                                    enableButtons(false);
                                    stopRecording();

                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
    }; 
 }
```

I am trying comparison of wav file and realtime writed wav file similarity. But real time wav file throw exception.

Comparison in compareTempFile() method.

```
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.musicg.dsp.Resampler.reSample(Resampler.java:43)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.musicg.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.extractFingerprint(FingerprintManager.java:72)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.musicg.wave.Wave.getFingerprint(Wave.java:329)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.musicg.wave.Wave.getFingerprintSimilarity(Wave.java:335)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.example.deneme.MainActivity.compareTempFile(MainActivity.java:178)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.example.deneme.MainActivity.stopRecording(MainActivity.java:169)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.example.deneme.MainActivity.access$2(MainActivity.java:155)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.example.deneme.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:292)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4470)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18593)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
11-06 05:01:36.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for the above error?

Comment: Please tell me if you found the solution, i have the same issue

Answer (score 4):

Instead of comparing with the temp raw file, compare your raw sound resource with the .wav file that is created after adding header and copying the data. So instead of using `compareTempFile()` method, use a method something like below:

```
function compareFile() {
    File file = new File(getFilename());
    Wave w1 = new Wave(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.selam));
    Wave w2 = new Wave(file.getPath());


    FingerprintSimilarity fps = w1.getFingerprintSimilarity(w2);
    float score = fps.getScore();
    float sim = fps.getSimilarity();
    System.out.println(sim+" buldum");
}
```

And yeah!! the name that you are using to store the recorded sound is dependent on the current time, that needs to be changed as the `getFilename()` is now called from two places. The complete working copy is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
private double currentTime;

private AudioRecord recorder = null;
private int bufferSize = 0;
private Thread recordingThread = null;
private boolean isRecording = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

setButtonHandlers();
enableButtons(false);

bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

}

private void setButtonHandlers() {
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

private void enableButton(int id,boolean isEnable){
        ((Button)findViewById(id)).setEnabled(isEnable);
}

private void enableButtons(boolean isRecording) {
        enableButton(R.id.btnStart,!isRecording);
        enableButton(R.id.btnStop,isRecording);
}

private String getFilename(){
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
        }

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + currentTime + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
}

private String getTempFilename(){
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
        }

        File tempFile = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

        if(tempFile.exists())
                tempFile.delete();

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
}

private void startRecording(){
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                                        RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

        int i = recorder.getState();
        if(i==1)
            recorder.startRecording();

        isRecording = true;

        recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                        writeAudioDataToFile();
                }
        },"AudioRecorder Thread");

        recordingThread.start();
}

private void writeAudioDataToFile(){
        byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        String filename = getTempFilename();
        FileOutputStream os = null;

        try {
                os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int read = 0;

        if(null != os){
                while(isRecording){
                        read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                        if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
                                try {
                                        os.write(data);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                }

                try {
                        os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}

private void stopRecording(){
        if(null != recorder){
                isRecording = false;

                int i = recorder.getState();
                if(i==1)
                    recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();

                recorder = null;
                recordingThread = null;
        }

        copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(),getFilename());
        compareTempFile();
}

private void compareTempFile() {
        File file = new File(getTempFilename());
        Wave w1 = new Wave(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.selam));
        Wave w2 = new Wave(file.getPath());


        FingerprintSimilarity fps = w1.getFingerprintSimilarity(w2);
        float score = fps.getScore();
        float sim = fps.getSimilarity();
        System.out.println(sim+" buldum");

}

private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename,String outFilename){
        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalAudioLen = 0;
        long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
        int channels = 2;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;

        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

        try {
                in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
                out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
                totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
                totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

                AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

                WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

                while(in.read(data) != -1){
                        out.write(data);
                }

                in.close();
                out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private void WriteWaveFileHeader(
                FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
                long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
                long byteRate) throws IOException {

        byte[] header = new byte[44];

        header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = 'I';
        header[2] = 'F';
        header[3] = 'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = 'W';
        header[9] = 'A';
        header[10] = 'V';
        header[11] = 'E';
        header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = 'm';
        header[14] = 't';
        header[15] = ' ';
        header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) channels;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8);  // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = 'd';
        header[37] = 'a';
        header[38] = 't';
        header[39] = 'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

        out.write(header, 0, 44);

}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                        case R.id.btnStart:{
                                AppLog.logString("Start Recording");
                                currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                                enableButtons(true);
                                startRecording();

                                break;
                        }
                        case R.id.btnStop:{
                                AppLog.logString("Start Recording");

                                enableButtons(false);
                                stopRecording();

                                break;
                        }
                }
        }
    }; 
 }
```

Comment: Can we directly feed data from MIC ? Like ,  FingerprintSimilarity fps = w1.getFingerprintSimilarity(INPUT.FromMIC);

Answer (score 0):

private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;

mucsicg library just works properly for comparing 2 sounds when using the sample rate at 8000 Hz